# How to force-redraw IE control on WM_SIZE?

Tags: winapi, activex

In my Win32 application, I embed Internet Explorer ActiveX control within a dialog. When the dialog is resized by the user, I process WM_SIZE event and set the size of the IE control to occupy the client rectangle of the dialog.

Although the resizing of the control works, the control itself does not refresh. I am wondering if there is some command I could send to the control to refresh/redraw itself. Regards.

Here is my DlgProc code to resize:

```
case WM_SIZE:   {
    HWND hX = GetDlgItem(hh, IDC_EXPLORER);
    if (hX) {
        RECT rc = { 0 };
        GetClientRect(hh, &rc);
        ::SetWindowPos(hX, 0, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
        // ::MoveWindow(hX, 0, 0, rc.right, rc.bottom, TRUE);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of SetWindowPos, I also tried MoveWindow. However, it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have code that does something similar.  A dialog that has a IE Ax control embedded on it (as well as a toolbar and statusbar).  All I do is a MoveWindow() with bRepaint=TRUE and IE will redraw.

wndIE is my member CWindow ATL wrapper, but if you're just using straight HWNDs, adapt MoveWindow() to that.

```
// Common private function to handle resizing of the child windows on our browser dialog.
void CBrowserWindow::resize_dialog_and_controls(RECT *rcClient) {

// Tell the toolbar to resize 
m_wndToolbar.SendMessage(TB_AUTOSIZE, 0, 0);

RECT rcTool;
m_wndToolbar.GetClientRect(&rcTool);
int iToolHeight = rcTool.bottom - rcTool.top;

// Tell the statusbar to auto-size
m_wndStatus.SendMessage(WM_SIZE, 0, 0);

// Now get the new height of the statusbar 
RECT rcStatus;   
m_wndStatus.GetClientRect(&rcStatus); 
int iStatusHeight = rcStatus.bottom - rcStatus.top;

// Now set the adjusted size of our IE host window
rcClient->top += iToolHeight;
rcClient->bottom -= iStatusHeight;

wndIE.MoveWindow(rcClient, true);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have updated my post with some code. MoveWindow doesn't seem to refresh the page either.